# Arrange coins on 3x3 table from vertical to horizontal

Tags: mechanical-puzzles

In 5 moves, rearrange the coins.
From 1st picture to 2nd picture.

[image]

Each move consists of rotate (right/left) 4 (in 2x2 grid) coins at one time.

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just rotate the table? Why bother doing all that?

Comment: Why even bother rotating table? Just look at the coins sideways. :)

Comment: Does the orientation of the coins matter?

Comment: What is the third coin in the picture?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 5 moves, as follows. Rotate bottom left clockwise, bottom right clockwise, top right anticlockwise, top left clockwise, bottom left clockwise.
>
>  [image]

Comment: You should probably move the pictures inside the spoiler tag.

Answer (score 5):

> The top-left and bottom-right coins are unchanged from the initial to the end state. From this, and given the need to move the coins efficiently, let us assume that it is not necessary to move those coins at all. This leaves us with only four possible moves rather than eight: clockwise or counter-clockwise rotation of either the lower-left or upper-right groups. It also means that there is only one way to move coins between these groups, via the center position. Four coins must be moved thus: the lower two in the left-hand column must become the right two coins in the upper row, and the upper two in the right-hand column must become the left two coins in the bottom row. This can be accomplished by alternating clockwise rotations of the upper-right and lower-left groups, by those four coins "flow" into their new locations. Five such rotations, beginning with either group, yields the solution.
>
>  [image]